# Unable to access MYSQL from Command line MAC OSX YOSEMITE 10.10.5, MYSQL 5.7.19(not first install) + (PHPMYADMIN)

Tags: mysql, terminal, osx-yosemite

(MYSQL installed from DMG and it is not my first install of MYSQL, maybe the 25th).

MYSQL seems to be in healthy condition with PHPmyAdmin. Works fine.

I am not understanding why access is permitted.

At one point I was able to log in using `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables` , now I can't.

Mysql site provides clear instructions on creating an init file to initalise 'RESET FILE' for Windows users that I believe should fix the issue. None for the OSX users(maybe I'm blind). It must have something to do with permission settings.

Would I need a `my.cnf` file into `/etc/` with the configuration that it knows where to find the PID file?(Unless its location is at `/usr/local/mysql` folder).

Hopefully there is enough information here for someone to understand my issue.

If my thread of assumptions/questions are unclear please do correct me, as I have browsed the net for the past 3 days and almost crying myself to sleep here.

MYSQL from command line is prompting errors, such as listed below:

1)Command entered:
`/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart`

```
ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
Starting MySQL
./usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /usr/local/mysql/data/Martins-iMac.err: Permission denied
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /usr/local/mysql/data/Martins-iMac.err: Permission denied
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 198: /usr/local/mysql/data/Martins-iMac.err: Permission denied
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /usr/local/mysql/data/Martins-iMac.err: Permission denied
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/Martins-iMac.pid).
```

Solution:
Gave access to the specified `.err` file.

2) `/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart`

```
cat: /usr/local/mysql/data/Martins-iMac.pid: Permission denied
ERROR! MySQL server process # is not running!
override rw-r----- _mysql/_mysql for /usr/local/mysql/data/Martins-iMac.pid? y
Starting MySQL
..................................................................................................... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/Martins-iMac.pid).
```

Aftermath:

PID file has vanished.

Full shutdown. No tears.

3) Computer is back on, PID file is present but this time it changes from Martins-iMac.pid to localhost.pid, not sure why the name change happens.

4)

```
Last login: Tue Jan 30 12:45:41 on console
UNKNOWN:~ martintolmusk$ sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart
Password:
ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
Starting MySQL
.Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/UNKNOWN.err'.
.................................................................................................... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/UNKNOWN.pid).
```

(File UNKNOWN.pid doesn’t exist in my data folder however UNKNOWN.err does)

*(In my preference pane I can see that MYSQL instance is running)

Have I got more than 1 instance running?

Sidenote: This is also present.

AutoStarting MySQL on Reboot
`sudo nano /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist`

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>KeepAlive</key>
<true />
<key>Label</key>
<string>com.mysql.mysqld</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
<string>/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
<string>--user=mysql</string>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

6) `UNKNOWN:~ martintolmusk$ mysql -u root -p`

```
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Using MYSQL generated password.

Also tried my admin password without success.

```
UNKNOWN:~ martintolmusk$ mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)


UNKNOWN:~ martintolmusk$ mysql -u martintolmusk
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'martintolmusk'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
UNKNOWN:~ martintolmusk$ mysql -u martintolmusk -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'martintolmusk'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

7)

```
UNKNOWN:support-files martintolmusk$ sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
```

Cannot get past this stage to begin with to possibly try and alter the password.

Please advise.

Kind regards,
Martin

Comment: You don't NEED TO YELL in the title.

Comment: @tadman point taken.